# Sort by key in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

This is my `Matrix` model:

```
Matrix  ->   Finding   ->    Norm   ->    Normtype
          (finding_id)     (norm_id)   (normtype_id)
```

I'd like to fetch Matrixes, sorted first by `finding_id`, then by `normtype_id`.

From what I've read, `orderBy` only applies to keys in the actual model, such as:

```
public function findings() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Finding')->orderBy('finding_id');
}
```

How can I do this in Eloquent?

Just to clarify, a `matrix` has many `findings`, and each `finding` belongs to a `norm`, and each `norm` has a `normtype`.

Comment: How do you image sorting by `finding_id` when a `matrix` can have many `findings`?

Answer (score 0):

When you put the `orderBy` call on a relation definition, you only change how the related models are sorted. If you want to sort by related model's attributes, you'll need to build a proper join yourself.

The following should do the trick in your case:

```
Matrix::join('findings', 'finding_id', 'findings.id')
  ->join('norms', 'findings.norm_id', 'norms.id)
  ->orderByRaw('finding_id, norms.normtype_id')
  ->get();
```